# Install Plone. Buildout now includes 'buildout-versions' (and part of the older 'buildout.dumppickedversions')

Tags: python, plone

I have this warning during installation plone:

```
$ bin/buildout
While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.
Error: Buildout now includes 'buildout-versions' (and part of the older 'buildout.dumppickedversions').
Remove the extension from your configuration and look at the 'show-picked-versions' option in buildout's documentation.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How about you remove the `buildout.dumppickedversions` extension and try again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Buildout 2.x or higher, remove `buildout.dumppickedversions` from extensions e.g.:

```
[buildout]
extensions =
# We don't need this in 2.x:
# buildout.dumppickedversions
```

Or use Buildout 1.7.x:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/buildout/buildout/1/bootstrap/bootstrap.py
$ bin/python bootstrap.py
```

Comment: Also be sure to double-check any buildout configuration files included via 'extends'.